# If regex has results and a result contains the word "wordpress" do this

Tags: php, regex

can you help me with the following code ?

```
if(preg_match_all('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $content, $results)) && ( WORDPRESS IS TRUE ) {...} ELSE {...}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe actually use the regular expression to test for that?

```
preg_match_all('!http://.+wordpress.*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $content, $results);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Just to have a knowledge, how can I add more than one words?

Comment: Follow this example: (wordpress|joomla|drupal|zenart|otherWord)

Comment: like `'!http://.(wordpress|joomla|drupal|zenart|otherWord).*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui'` ?

Comment: ^^ you catch on quick, but you might need: '!http://.?(wordpress|joomla|drupal|zenart|otherWord).*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui' < you forgot a ? modifier

Comment: Thank you friend. I dont have the money for tutoring so I am trying by myself.

Comment: More than half the programmers I know are self-taught. So welcome to the club :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Regex for the second part:

```
$WP=(stripos($content,'wordpress')!==false);
```

`$WP` is now either `true`  or `false` (contains or doesn't contain 'wordpress')

Answer (score 0):

```
if(
(preg_match_all('#http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)#Ui', $content, $results)) && 
stripos($content, 'wordpress') !== false)
{

}else{

}
```